# simple Se v4 Grid, node is stuck at “Sending registration event”. How to diagnose?

Tags: selenium-grid

I’m transitioning a small Grid setup with a hub and two nodes to a new hub. The problem I have is that the node is stuck at “Sending registration event” for the new hub.

I have the logging set at FINEST but I do not see any errors in the logs.

The node config seems fine, I’m able to get my node to register to the old hub server fine. I have tested that TCP connections work from the node to the new hub at ports 4442 and 4443 and also from the new hub to node at port 5555. I’ve traced the network connections and see the node connects to the hub at ports 4442 and 4443 and the new hub connects to the node at port 5555. The beginning communication conversation looks the same as the working setup on the old hub.

hub:  `java -jar /opt/selenium4/selenium-server-4.16.1.jar hub --log-level FINEST --log-timestamp-format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

node:   `java -jar selenium-server-4.16.1.jar node --host 10.103.66.160 --hub http://10.103.163.24  --log-level FINEST`

How does a node register?

UPDATE: So I did find a little bit about how the node registers from this wiki page: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/components/#distributor

What else can I check for?

UPDATE: I did find one difference - the new hub server is IPv4 only.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround - start Se Grid as distributed so each component is running as a separate process.